# How to construct table with dynamic input fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script where you can (as admin) select how many input-fields there will be in a question form. Some of the fields are non optional, but som are (as many as you like).

The table in MySQL for collecting the answers looks like this:

```
id | userid | fname | ename | seat | optional
```

If the admin want it to be two optional input-fields then the result of one filled form would take three tows in the table:

```
| 5 | 3 | Peter | Pan | 4 |            |
|   | 3 |       |     |   | opt.value1 |
|   | 3 |       |     |   | opt.value2 |
```

Is this really the best way to store this in? How would you solve it?

And also, how can I make shure that the userid is unique for the user? I can't use the auto-increment key value thing in MySQL because the same value is on three rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i learned it you have to use multiple tables. Like this:

Table1:

```
id | userid | fname | ename | seat
```

Table2:

```
userid | optional
```

Table2.userid is a reference to Table1.userid

Then the fields that has to be filed can be put into the first table and all the optional in the second.

If i follow your example your database should look like this:

Table1:

```
id | userid | fname | ename | seat
 5 |      3 | Peter |   Pan |    4
```

Table2:

```
userid | optional
     3 | opt.value1
     3 | opt.value2
```

By the way, why do you have both id and userid in Table1?

Comment: Seems like a better solution! I have both id and userid because id has to do with wich question-form it is. Perhaps its confusing here.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to store "id" and "optional" values in a separate table.
Then pull the information you want from it for each "id".